# Are components that aren't visible still painted?

Tags: java, swing, paint

Seems like the obvious answer is no, but I want to find out anyway.

If I have panel with lots of complex components in it that would take a while to load, and then had another very basic panel over the top, covering it completely, would the background panel still be painted in the paint method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can paint components on top of one another. What shows up below the top panel depends on the opacity of the top panel.

See the [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) example. Also take a look at the Table of Contents for the `How to Use Layered Panes` example.

Edit:

> Seems like the obvious answer is no

I understand the question better now. You are asking if the painting of the complex components will still be painted even if an opaque panel is painted of top of the complex panel. The answer is YES the bottom components will be painted, before the top component is painted.

Each Swing component is responsible for painting its child components. Generally components are layed out in 2-dimensions, but a layout like the OverlayLayout does allow you to paint components on top of one another. In this case all components are painted, unless you make a component invisible. Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class OverlayPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static int ctr = 1;

    public OverlayPanel(String name)
    {
        setName( name );
        add( new JLabel("Label " + ctr++) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("Painting: " + getName());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(panel) );

        panel.add( new OverlayPanel("first") );
        panel.add( new OverlayPanel("second") );

        JPanel third = new OverlayPanel("third");
        third.setVisible(false);
        panel.add(third);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OverlayPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking about whether covering a component will prevent it from being considered "dirty" by the RepaintManager.

Answer (score 3):

(Edit: camickr's answer is the real correct one)

Java does have a repaint manager that makes sure only "dirty" regions of a component are repainted. More info here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#mgr

However, whether the repaint manager can do its job right probably depends on your code (and might even be system dependent?).

The best way to test this would be to extend a component and override its paintComponent() method so that it prints a message when the component is repainted. Add that component to the JPanel that is being covered, and look to see whether that component's paintComponent() method is being triggered.

Comment: +1 You understood the intent of the question better than I. However it is not the RepaintManager that decides whether the bottom components should be painted or not. Every Swing component is responsible for painting all its child components. So by default the bottom component will be painted even when there is a top component. You can change this behaviour by making the bottom component invisible. See my simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think your answer is the most correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try do `System.out.println("painting..")` in `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` in both `JPanel` and see what happens.

Comment: That will only tell you that the underlying JPanel is being repainted,  not what's going on with its child components.

Comment: Yes, of course. But this simple check helps sometimes.

Comment: But it belongs in a component belonging to the JPanel, not the JPanel itself.

Comment: Then you can check components also.